# Populating cells until last row with a formula VBA

Tags: vba

[ExcelSheetImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDVqG.png)
I want to populate the cells until the last row and the last column. The number of columns and rows vary for each excel sheet I am going through.

So far I have the code below for populating all the rows in column C but it doesn't compile

```
Sub populate()
Dim lastrow, lastcol As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'finds last row in B
Range(lastrow, 3).Formula = "=sum(A2:B2)"  'populates cells in C with formula 
until last row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range` expects two cells a start and an end or a string. `Cells` take a row and column

```
Sub populate()
Dim lastrow, lastcol As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'finds last row in B
Sheet1.Range("C2",Sheet1.Cells(lastrow, 3).Formula = "=sum(A2:B2)"  'populates cells in C with formula 
End Sub
```